# Why does span require having a pivot in each row?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does span require having a pivot in each row? Is there is a row with all zeroes, doesn't that mean there is at least one solution, meaning that the columns in the matrix do span? Thank you.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you're asking:

> Why is it true that the columns of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ span $\Bbb R^m$ only if the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a pivot in every row?

This question can be answered as follows.  First, note that the statement "the columns of $A$ span $\Bbb R^m$" is equivalent to the statement "the equation $Ax = b$ has a solution $x \in \Bbb R^n$ for every $b \in \Bbb R^m$". Remember also that the point of row-reduction is to make solving systems of equations easier.  In particular: suppose that $R$ is the row-reduced form of $A$, and that applying these row operations to $b$ produces the vector $c$.  Then the equations
$$
Ax = b, \qquad Rx = c
$$
have exactly the same solutions. So, $Ax = b$ will have a solution for every $b$ if and only if $Rx = c$ has a solution for every $c$.  However, if $R$ has a final row with only zeros, then the last row of the equation $Rx = c$ will look like
$$
0x_1 + 0x_2 + \cdots + 0x_n = c_m
$$
which will only have a solution if $c_m = 0$.  So, $Rx = c$ can only have a solution for **every** $c$ if $R$ does not have a row of zeros.  So, $Rx = c$ can only have a solution for every $c$ if $R$ has a pivot in every row.  So, $Ax = b$ can only have a solution for every $b$ if $R$ has a pivot in every row.  So, the columns of $A$ will span $\Bbb R^m$ only if $R$ (the reduced form of $A$) has a pivot in every row.

Comment: One point that I gloss over in this answer is that the process of going from $Ax = b$ to $Rx = c$ is reversible.  That is: for **every** possible equation $Rx = c$, we can find an equation $Ax = b$ that would be reduced to $Rx = c$.

Comment: Hi, can I say that the statement "The columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$ is also equivalent to $ColA= \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @MathLover Yes those are equivalent